# Logarithmic Integration

Tags: integration

Show that

$$\int_{\ln\frac{3}{2}}^{\ln2}\frac{\exp(2x)+1}{\exp(2x)-1}\mathrm dx=\ln\frac{9}{5}$$

Comment: divide the numerator and denominator by  $e^{x}$ and then use substitution.

Comment: Note: You can get strings of $>1$ letter in the superscript by putting them in braces {}: `$e^ax$` escapes as $e^ax$ and `$e^{ax}$` as $e^{ax}$

Comment: Beside the good trick vnd gave, it seems that a simple substitution could be used first to get the antiderivative. After using vnd's trick, you could also recognize very simple functions and their derivatives.

Comment: one objective function of the indefinite integral is given by $$\log \left(1-e^{2 x}\right)-x$$

Comment: what would you do?

Comment: i would calculate the given integral

Comment: But how did you get that?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Set $e^x=u\implies x=\ln u\implies dx?,x\ln\dfrac32\implies u=\dfrac32$ etc.

$$\int\dfrac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}dx=\int\dfrac{u^2-1}{(u^2+1)u}du$$

Use  [partial-fraction decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html) on $$\dfrac{u^2-1}{(u^2+1)u}=\dfrac{Au+B}{u^2+1}+\dfrac Cu$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got the denominator:$(u^2+1)u$

Comment: @DanJa78912, $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2=u^2$ and $dx=\dfrac{du}u$

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}=\frac{1-e^{2x}+2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}-1}=-1+\frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}-1},
$$
we get
$$
\int \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}\,dx=-x+\ln(e^{2x}-1)+C.
$$
Tell me if you have problems inserting the limits.

Comment: Yes i do have problems

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{\ln \frac{3}{2}}^{\ln2} \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}dx$$
$$=\int_{\ln \frac{3}{2}}^{\ln2} \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}dx$$
$$=\int_{\ln \frac{3}{2}}^{\ln2} \frac{d(e^{x}-e^{-x})}{(e^{x}-e^{-x})}$$
$$=[\ln |e^{x}-e^{-x}|]_{\ln \frac{3}{2}}^{\ln2}$$
$$=\ln |e^{\ln2}-e^{-\ln 2}|-\ln |e^{\ln \frac{3}{2}}-e^{-\ln \frac{3}{2}}|$$
$$=\ln |\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2}{3}}|$$
$$=\ln \frac{\frac{3}{2}}{\frac{5}{6}}$$
$$=\ln \frac{9}{5}$$
$$$$
$$$$