# Logarithmic variables being used while integrating.

Tags: integration

Show that
$$\int_{\ln\frac{3}{2}}^{\ln2}\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\,\mathrm dx=\ln\frac{9}{5}$$

How would you integrate this logarithmic function in order to obtain $\ln(\frac{9}{5})$.

Comment: Are you the same person as the OP in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496789/logarithmic-integration) asked just some time ago?

Comment: @mikep i would guess different persons but same excersise sheet ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider $$I=\int\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\,dx=\int\frac{\cosh(x)}{\sinh(x)}\,dx=\log\big(\sinh(x)\big)+K=\log(e^{x}-e^{-x})+K$$

**Edit**

Even simpler as @incognito commented $$I=\int\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\,dx=\int\frac{(e^{x}-e^{-x})'}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}\,dx=\log(e^{x}-e^{-x})+K$$

Comment: Ya that's what I thought. Even hyperbolic functions are not needed. Take denominator as Z and you're done with the integral.

Comment: @incognito. Yes, for sure : the famous $\int \frac {u'(x)}{u(x)}\,dx$

Comment: Exactly Sir. +1.

Comment: @incognito. Ia dded to my answer quoting you ! Please, forget *Sir* !! You make me feeling older that I am (and I am) ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Sorry if you felt that but I was trying to make myself feel younger than what I am (and I am)! Cheers...

Comment: @incognito. Don't be sorry at all ! I was just kidding you, lucky man. If I may ask, what are you doing and where are you ?

Comment: Why do you use $K$ as the constant instead of $C$?

Comment: It is a constant. You can name it as you want as long as you know that it is the integration constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: first use the subsitution $u=e^x$, then use the substitution $sec(\theta) = u$

I'm going to ignore the bounds for the integral for now, I think you can figure those out once you know how to calculate the indefinite case.

first let $u=e^x$, then $du = e^x dx$, we get
$\int \frac{u+1/u}{u-1/u}\frac{1}{u}du$ = $\int \frac{u+1/u}{u^2-1}du$

Now you can either use substitution $sec(\theta) = u$ or $sin(\theta) = u$, let say we use $sin(\theta) = u$

then we get $\int \frac{sin \theta+1/sin\theta}{-cos^2 \theta} cos\theta d\theta$ = $\int -tan\theta d\theta -\int \frac{1}{sin\theta cos\theta} d\theta$

$\int \frac{1}{sin\theta cos\theta} d\theta$ can be solve by using one more $v=sin\theta$ substitution

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: still the same method.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\, dx=\int \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)}\, d\left(e^x\right)=\int\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^x\left(e^{2x}-1\right)}\, d\left(e^x\right)$$

Let $u=e^x$.

$$\int \frac{u^2+1}{u(u-1)(u+1)}\, du=\int\left(\frac{-1}{u}+\frac{1}{u-1}+\frac{1}{u+1}\right)\, du$$

$$=-\int \frac{du}{u}+\int\frac{d(u-1)}{u-1}+\int\frac{d(u+1)}{u+1}$$

$$=-\ln|e^x|+\ln|e^x-1|+\ln|e^x+1|+C$$

Note this antiderivative is continuous when $x>1$. And $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}$ is continuous when $x>1$ as well. So you'll have no problems calculating the definite integral.